# Optimizing SQL query's where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, between

I have a SQL query which has a where condition

```
WHERE
  quarter IN ('2015 Q1', '2014 Q4', '2015 Q2', '2015 Q3', '2015 Q4',
              '2016 Q1', '2016 Q2', '2016 Q3', '2016 Q4', '2017 Q1',
              '2017 Q2', '2017 Q3')
```

Every quarter I hardcode the last Quarter. Is there an optimized way of writing it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work (not sure -- it should be -- is faster):

```
WHERE
  quarter >= '2014 Q4' and quarter <= '2017 Q3'
```

however, ideally, you table should have two fields: year (int), quarter (int: 1,2,3,4)

Comment: Will try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in which you store the (valid) quarters, e.g.

```
create table quarters (
   quarter varchar2(20) primary key
);
```

Then insert the valid quarters in there:

```
insert into quarters(quarter) values ('2015 Q1');
...
insert into quarters(quarter) values ('2017 Q3');
```

such that you then can write:

```
select *
from myTable m join quarter q on m.quarter = q.quarter
```

Thereby, you do not have to alter the query every time but just to insert a new tuple in the `quarters`-table.

Comment: I just wanna make changes to where condition. Creating a new table would be a hassle. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
WHERE quarter >= '2014 Q4'
```

This assumes that you don't have future quarters or other strings.  If you have other strings, then:

```
WHERE quarter >= '2014 Q4' AND quarter LIKE '____ Q_'
```

Comment: Nice. I never though of that.Thanks. Will try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could give every row an auto-incrementing* ID, so you could write `where ID > 0`

Using IDs is the standard way of doing this, although, not the only way.

If you have other stuff in this table, don't auto-increment, although you should have just quarters.

Comment: Oh yeahh. The table has lot of data .Quarter is just a small part of it. Thanks though..:)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 where quarter between '2014 Q4' and '2017 Q3';
```

You could change the between condition to see the result you want.

Comment: Between condition is what I was thinking. Still when evry new quarte starts , I'll have to change the '201 Q3' to '2017 Q4'. Is there any other way, wherein I do not have to do it every quarter?

Comment: I did't really get what you mean, but you can extend the '2017 Q3' quarter to something like '2020 Q4'. So even new record come in, the where condition still able to filter it out.